# Modifying Servlet.xml of Spring

Tags: xml, spring, servlets

Below is my servlet.xml.I need to add following node

```
<bean id="myController2"class="com.restcontrollers.MyController2"></bean>
```

at run time to this xml.
  Is this possible?If yes, how?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xsi:schemaLocation="
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd">

<context:component-scan base-package="com.restcontrollers"/>

  <bean id="myController1"class="com.restcontrollers.MyController1">
  </bean>

<mvc:annotation-driven />
</beans>
```

Any kind of help will be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Depending on what you are trying to do there might be viable solutions that would be much better

Comment: You can add that line, but the config wouldn't be reread.

Comment: Thanks for help.Actually i m trying to load new controller at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

You have three options:

**Option 1:**
If its ok to have the bean configured in bean definitions xml and instantiation can be done at run-time on first request, you can create myController2 with lazy-init attribute as:

```
    <bean id="myController2" class="com.restcontrollers.MyController2" lazy-init="true"></bean>
```

You can find more details about it [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-lazy-init).

**Option 2:**
By using Spring AOP @Configurable annotation which marks a class as eligible for Spring-driven configuration(like objects instantiated with the 'new' operator).

```
    @Configurable
        public class MyController2 {
        ...
        }
```

and specifying this

```
    <context:spring-configured/>
```

in servlet.xml.
You can find more information about this spring aop way [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-using-aspectj).

**Option 3:**
In the class which you want to invoke the new myController2:
Access applicationContext and create bean as:

```
    ApplicationContext ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("servlet.xml");
    MyController2 myController2 = new MyController2();
    ctx.getAutowireCapableBeanFactory().autowireBeanProperties(myController2, AutowireCapableBeanFactory.AUTOWIRE_BY_TYPE, true);
```